# mutt: Delay in emails delivery

Tags: email, mutt

It is the first time I am sending emails from Bash. For a test I have sent about 80 emails with `mutt` to (and from) my GMail address. Not all emails have been delivered in the 24 hours following me sending the email.

24 hours later, when I send a new email with `mutt`, the new email is delivered and a few old emails that haven't been delivered before are being delivered. I can then repeat the process (sending new emails) and every time some old emails are being delivered in the same time up to the point that all 80 old emails are delivered.

- What is going on?
- Assuming I don't overshoot the limit rate of emails sent/received, how can I make sure that all emails are being delivered in the following minutes/hours after the `mutt` command has been executed?
- How can I make sure that a given email has been delivered?

---

I am using Mac OSX El capitano.

Comment: Are you sending the emails with a local MTA (sendmail etc) or with SMTP to another server?

Comment: I'll probably need some help and definitions to answer your question. I would have thought SMTP was a protocol while MTA is a software to manage emails. I sent the email first with sendmail and then later I tried with mutt and got the same issue (I want to use MIME so I am focusing on mutt now). I saw the reception on my gmail account via the URL `gmail.com/mail/path/to#inbox`

Comment: `mutt` can either use sendmail to use your local MTA (which send then your mails to the gmail server or you can configure `mutt` to send the mails to another mailserver (which will relay your mails to its destination). The default is to use sendmail, so the real problem is probably not `mutt` but your local mail server. I suspect that for some reason your local server has sometimes problems sending your mails to google, and once you send more it also tries to deliver those delayed mails.

Comment: I set as few parameters as I could to use mutt. I pretty much only set my imap user and password

Answer (score 0):

Check `tail -f /var/log/mail.log` and look for 4.X.X Response codes (delays) if there's nothing there then mutt isn't ending with local email (or you have syslog re-routing your maillogs elsewhere)

You should either configure [mutt to use a smart-host](https://medium.com/@stessyco/gmail-from-the-command-line-with-mutt-mac-os-x-92d047bcd74f) with auth

**~/.muttrc**

```
set imap_user = “YOUR-USERNAME@gmail.com”
set imap_pass = “YOUR-PASSWORD”
set smtp_url = “smtp://YOUR-USERNAME@smtp.gmail.com:587/”
set smtp_pass = “YOUR-PASSWORD”
set from = “YOUR-USERNAME@gmail.com”
set realname = “YOUR NAME”
set folder = “imaps://imap.gmail.com:993"
set spoolfile = “+INBOX”
set postponed = “+[Gmail]/Drafts”
set header_cache = ~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir = ~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file = ~/.mutt/certificates
set move = no
set smtp_authenticators = ‘gssapi:login’
```

or configure your local email system [(postfix is easiest)](http://www.developerfiles.com/how-to-send-emails-from-localhost-mac-os-x-el-capitan/) with your email service.

If your emails are from gmail (please update the question if otherwise)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I don't have any `/var/log/mail.log` file. I have `/var/log/mail.log.0.gz`, `/var/log/mail.log.1.gz`, `/var/log/mail.log.2.gz` and `/var/log/mail.log.3.gz` files though. After desarchiving them, it appears that it concerns `postfix` only. For the moment the only thing I have in `~/.muttrc` is `set from="My_Name <address@gmail.com>"`. I will make the modifications you suggest and give another try.

Comment: Sounds like mutt is attempting to send email directly to mail exchangers which is unsupported/incorrect.  Mutt should connect to MTA, go with the mutt authenticated relay.   Are you sending from gmail?

Comment: Yes, I am sending from gmail.

Comment: Then you MUST auth, Gmail requires this and future email with reject per DMARC policy change https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707

Comment: There is a lot to learn for me. I did not know the term DMARC for example. I ran `set imap_user = “YOUR-USERNAME@gmail.com”; set imap_pass = “YOUR-PASSWORD”` directly on Bash (but did not write it on `~muttrc`). Again, most emails got delivered. Those who did not get delivered at first place were so at subsequent use of `mutt`. Could it it really be an issue of authentification?

Comment: IMAP is a receive protocol only,  SMTP is the connection between mutt and gmail, your connection was directly to those MX servers, usually blocked by your ISP, but apparently not in your area

Comment: And yes,  you need to configure SMTP Auth